# Deux personnes ont marché sur des abeilles : ambiguïté ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

La phrase suivante est ambigüe:

> Deux personnes ont marché sur des abeilles.

Soit ils ont marché ensemble sur les mêmes abeilles, soit chacun sur plusieurs abeilles ou alors chacun sur une abeille ce qui, malgré tout, reste un pluriel.

La phrase: « deux personnes ont marché sur une abeille », semble grammaticalement moins correcte mais en un sens plus précise.

Toutefois l'ambiguïté reste présente car il se peut que ces deux personnes aient marché sur la même abeille, auquel cas seul une des deux se serait fait piquer.

Comment devrais-je reformuler cette phrase pour éliminer l'ambiguïté ?

Comment: Pour avoir lequel des sens proposés ?

Comment: Typiquement, il existe des formulations où l'ambiguïté ne peut pas être éliminée : 5 personnes ont porté 4 tables. On peut essayer de dissocier la lecture à 20 tables (5x4) de celle à 4 tables (5=>4), mais pour l'interprétation à 4 tables, on ne peut pas associer simplement les 5 personnes aux 4 tables...

Comment: Je dirais que le contexte sert à lever l'ambiguité. Sans contexte et si cette ambiguité est potentiellement problématique, sans-doute vaudrait-il mieux reformuler la phrase.

Comment: 5e § : Dans la phrase il n'est pas question de piqûre : rien ne dit que l'abeille ait été écrasée par la première, ou que le dard de cette dernière ait pu percer la semelle de la première personne. Il faut compléter la phrase : vous parler d'une action humaine, sans préciser les circonstance, et vous induisez la réaction d'une abeille sans fournir le résultat de l'action précédente, et, sans donner "son point de vue".

Answer (score 2):

Je ne décèle aucune ambiguïté, soit deux (ou plus) personnes ont marché sur **une** abeille (singulier) ou bien sur **plusieurs** abeilles (pluriel).

- Une personne a marché sur une abeille.
- Deux personnes ont marché sur une abeille.
- Une personne a marché sur des abeilles.
- Plusieurs personnes ont marché sur des abeilles.

Sinon, précisément dans la phrase indiquée, tu pourrais dire :

> Deux personnes ont, chacune, marché sur une abeille.
>   Deux personnes ont, chacune, marché sur des abeilles.

Comment: Est-ce que la définition même d'une ambiguïté ne tient pas au fait qu'on peut inférer plusieurs choses différentes ? Pourquoi dire ne déceler aucune ambiguïté ici ?

Comment: @GAMPUB: Pour moi, la phrase originale signifie que "Deux personnes ont marché sur *plusieurs* abeilles", il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté.

Comment: On peut dire ça dans le cas où chacune des deux personnes a marché sur une abeille différente...

Comment: Merci beaucoup à la personne qui a donné un vote négatif, mais une explication serait la bienvenue.

Comment: l'explication est en place. Désolé pour cette incompréhension.

Comment: Je pense aussi que cette réponse n'explique pas grand chose. Cf. la réponse de biozic.

Answer (score 1):

Ces quatre phrases décrivent des situations différentes :

- Deux personnes ont marché sur la même abeille
- Deux personnes ont marché chacune sur une abeille différente
- Deux personnes ont marché sur les mêmes abeilles
- Deux personnes ont marché chacune sur des abeilles différentes

Seules les trois dernières me paraissent coller avec la phrase initiale "Deux personnes ont marché sur des abeilles".